# How to check a list of records has a value and flag it as a dupe

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I have a list of records that contains duplicates.  I would like to keep the duplicates in the list for other reasons, but flag if the field "Name" has a the same value appearing more than once.

Here is the list (truncated for brevity)

```
Products__c:{employee__c=0030S000001b16DQAQ, Name=Blender},
Products__c:{employee__c=0030S000001b16DQAQ, Name=Blender},
Products__c:{employee__c=0030S000001b16DQAQ, Name=Food Processor}
```

The name field has the value "Blender" twice.  What specific code is needed to flag that a duplicate value exist?

Comment: Is the `Name` field the only thing you're taking into consideration to determine whether or not something is a duplicate, or is there more to it? Do you have an idea of how exactly you plan to 'flag' duplicates (do you need the index of the duplicate(s) in your list, or just to have knowledge of which values are duplicated)?

Comment: Yes, the name field is the only field I need to consider if the record is a duplicate.  It would be helpful to also have a simple string list of the duplicate values as well using the "Name" field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's any escaping from the need to loop over your input in this case. The only real question to figure out is *how do I know if I've seen this particular value before*?

Collections in Apex are immensely helpful, and in this case, a `Set` is what we want.

The `Set` class provides a `.contains()` method, which is an extremely fast way to determine if something already exists in the set.

An example implementation:

```
Set<String> encounteredNames = new Set<String>();

// I've chosen to store the duplicate names in a set instead of a list, because
//   that prevents us from having a collection that could contain duplicate entries
//   for our duplicate names.
Set<String> duplicateNames = new Set<String>();

for(Products__c prod :productsList){
    if(encounteredNames.contains(prod.Name)){
        // Inside this if block, we know that the name is a duplicate, so
        //   add it to our duplicates set
        duplicateNames.add(prod.Name);
    }else{
        // Inside this else block, we know this is the first time we've encountered
        //   this particular name.
        // Add it to the encountered set so we can detect duplicates in successive
        //   iterations of the loop
        encounteredNames.add(prod.Name);
    }
}

// If you really want a List of duplicate names rather than a set (sometimes, Lists
//   are more appropriate), the conversion is simple.
// The List class has a constructor that allows you to pass in a Set.
// The downside to this approach is that the duplicate names won't be in any particular
//   order (though List.sort() could be used if you wanted them sorted in
//   ascending order)
List<String> duplicateNameList = new List<String>(duplicateNames);
```